# Grepping subdomains of particular URLs in text files

Tags: regex, grep

I have a dictionary with a ton of text files containing various urls. I want to grep all subdomains of a particular url. For example, a text file could look like this:

```
https://subdomain1.stage.domain.tld/[...]
https://subdomain2.stage.domain.tld/test/[...]
https://subdomain3.pre.domain.tld/[...]
https://subdomain4.prod.domain.tld/files/[...]
```

I want to extract all subdomains of **.stage.domain.tld**, in this case *subdomain1* and *subdomain2* whereas subdomain could have a-A,0-9 and -_ characters.

After failing to figure it out myself, I need to ask for help. I have tried several attemps, the closest I could get is

```
grep -r -i '(http|https)://[^/"]+.stage.domain.tld' .
```

But it does not extract the subdomains. Any suggestions what is wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU `grep`, you can use the following PCRE based `grep` command:

```
grep -oP 'https?://\K[\w-]+(?=\.stage\.domain\.tld)' file
```

See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/HKAC8g). **Regex details**:

- `https?://` - `http://` or `https://`
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `[\w-]+` - one or more letters, digits, `_` or `-`
- `(?=\.stage\.domain\.tld)` - a positive lookahead, immediately to the right, there must be a `.stage.domain.tld` string.

With `sed`, assuming all URLs are at the start of separate lines:

```
sed -En 's~https?://([[:alnum:]-]+)\.stage\.domain\.tld.*~\1~p' file
```

See [this online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/6i25DM). It matches the same way as the `grep` command, just `.*` is added to match the rest of the lines. `\1` replaces with whole match with the Group 1 contents, and `-n` suppresses the default line output and `p` prints the final results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked :) To search a dictionary I just need to add -r command.